# react: addEventListener is not a function error

Tags: reactjs

i have this div inside my render method in a component

```
<div ref={node => this.domNode = node} style={this.getStyle()}>{ this.props.children }</div>
```

when i do this in componentDidMount

```
this.domNode.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDrag);
```

there is an error

```
this.domNode.addEventListener is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a ReactDOM.findDOMNode around it.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.domNode).addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDrag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguemnt (`node`) of your ref callback can be `null`. You need to check that before you bind your listener.

> Note that when the referenced component is unmounted and whenever the ref changes, the old ref will be called with null as an argument.

from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

Comment: In what lifecycle function are you calling `addEventListener`?

Comment: i did this, if (this.domNode != null) {
                   this.domNode.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDrag);
            } and i still have the same error

Comment: i call it in componentDidMount

Comment: i think cause this.domNode return a react element which not have addeventlistener as a function but i am not sure

Comment: If you have the ref on a div the node should be an actual dom node

Comment: when i log this.domNode  it logged a constructor

Comment: Could you add some curly braces on your ref callback? `{this.domNode = node}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version `16.6.3` of React and I also had your problem and it was solved using this method.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.domNode);
    if(domNode) {
      domNode.addEventListener('mousedown', this.props. onDrag);
    }
}
```